# Is mastered Ultra Instinct the same as Super Saiyan Silver?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

*V Jump* magazine has released a picture of Goku with silver hair and a lot of people in the web is talking about "Super Saiyan Silver" and that it has to be mastered Ultra Instinct.

Is there any official confirmation or refutation that mastered Ultra Instinct is Super Saiyan Silver?

[image: low-res image of silver-haired Goku]

[image: another image of silver-haired Goku]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question would be "yes" and "no"! The transformation is called Mastered Ultra Instinct and not Super Saiyan Silver, while the color of Goku's hair is Silver (can be compared to the Super Saiyan God transformation).

Akira Toriyama's original designs for the same have also been released. Also, the designs of new figurines of this Mastered Ultra Instinct transformation have been released. Scans also indicate that Mastered Ultra Instinct Goku is also going to be included in the new DLC for *Xenoverse 2*.

[image: Akira Toriyama's design of Mastered Ultra Instinct]

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a simple reason why Mastered Ultra Instinct cannot be "Super Saiyan Silver": Ultra Instinct is not restricted to Saiyans. Theoretically, any of the Z Fighters could learn it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not Super Saiyan Silver, because Ultra Instinct can be used by anyone. Whis also said Gods of Destruction were striving to reach this state which is currently the most difficult thing to do.

Comment: We havent seen the next episodes, but Jiren's last aura in the preview looks a lot like Ultra Instinct. So I would place my bet Goku's Ultra Instinct form as he currently looks can be achieved by anyone and not only saiyans